# Why did my Microsoft Add-in suddenly stop showing as an option in F12 devtools?

Tags: outlook, internet-explorer-11, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, devtools

At one point I was able to see our Outlook add-in app in the target options in f12 devtools for troubleshooting, but sometime last month it stopped showing up there.  My colleagues are stumped, and I can't find much online in the way of troubleshooting.

I tried checking my Windows version and Outlook version against others who can see it in their devtools, but we're all on Windows 10 enterprise v1803, Outlook v1910, and IE 11.  I've tried many things over the month since this happened like rebooting my PC, making sure I have the latest updates from IT, refreshing the options, running some commands I found online for targeting the right browser for devtools, etc.  No change.

Another peculiar thing is that I'm seeing some completely different things in the Add-in than they are, like button alignments and div widths and such.  I had our dev environment looking perfect on my end, but when a few people on the team screenshared with me there were a number of styling issues I can't reproduce.  Even weirder, nobody experiences these issues in O365, it's just the desktop Outlook app on our Windows machines.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this would be very greatly appreciated.

Steps I take to produce the issue:

1. Click on manifest icon for our app in Outlook ribbon.  App loads in the sidebar.
2. Open F12 devtools (both 32 and 64 bit for good measure from the System32 and SysWOW64 directories).
3. App is not in the target list.  Click refresh, still not in the list.

FYI, any IE 11 windows I have open show up there, just not my app.

Comment: Can you please inform the detailed steps for producing this issue. With the above description, we are not able to produce this issue. If you provide the steps then we can try to follow it and try to check for the issue. It can help to understand the issue properly and we can provide suggestions for it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Sure, I'll add that now.

Comment: @LynneRang Could you double-check the version of Windows 10 on the machines with this issue? Starting in Windows 10 version 1903, the latest version of Office will use Edge WebView instead of IE to render add-ins. And Edge WebView has a different debugger. I know you checked the version already, but this is the closest change that matches the symptoms you describe. More info about this at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT, thanks so much for your comment, you are the best.  I mistyped the version and am indeed on 1903.  I'll check out this Edge Webview debugger and report back.  If that checks out, the remaining mystery to me is that the colleagues I checked with said they are also on 1903.  Is there any chance a different minor version of 1903 or new vs older machine would result in colleagues still having the add-in show in F12 devtools and seeing UI differences to me?

Comment: @LynneRang It depends on both the Windows version and the Office version, so the Office version is the other variable to check.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Windows 10 version 1903, the latest version of Office will use Edge WebView instead of IE to render add-ins. Edge WebView requires a different debugger (not the F12 debugger) called Microsoft Edge DevTools. You can find out more about it [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-edge-webview-for-office-add-ins/).